# What's the proper way to format and pass a json file as an object of parameters into a pandas function?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I've got a JSON file that contains the parameters/options for pandas' `read_excel` function. I'm having trouble passing them into that function call.

JSON file is structured similar to this:

```
{
    "io": "~/home/test.xlsx",
    "sheet_name": "Sheet1",
    "header": 0,
    "usecols": 2,
    "engine": "xlrd",
    "converters": {
            "col1": "np.float64",
            "col2": "np.float64"
    }
}
```

And I call it in my Python script like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
with open('json.json', 'r') as opened:

        options = json.loads(opened.read())

        import_pd_df = pd.read_excel(**options)

        print(import_pd_df)
```

When I have the options declared as a dictionary within the Python script and remove the double quotes that are around `np.float64`, the script works. But when I move the options to the JSON file, it fails while trying to parse the `np.float64`.

The error I get is: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Is there a way to properly format the JSON to be used as options in the function?

Comment: have you tried json.load() instead of loads()?

Comment: Use `"float64"` instead of `"np.float64"`

Answer (score 1):

`np.float64` is a numpy dtype that is also a callable (which it must be a callable in order to be a converter from `pandas` perspective). `"np.float64"` is a string that cannot be called. You need to convert the string you've stored in the JSON file (`"np.float64"`) into the callable desired (`np.float64`). You *could* do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

with open('json.json', 'r') as opened:
        options = json.loads(opened.read())
        for col, converter in options["converters"].items():
                exec('options["converters"]["{0}"] = {1}'.format(col, converter))
        import_pd_df = pd.read_excel(**options)
        print(import_pd_df)
```

If we step through with `pdb`, it's easy to verify the column converters get changed to a `np.float64`:

```
-> import_pd_df = pd.read_excel(**options)
(Pdb) l
  5     with open('json.json', 'r') as opened:
  6         options = json.loads(opened.read())
  7         for col, converter in options["converters"].items():
  8             exec('options["converters"]["{0}"] = {1}'.format(col, converter))
  9         import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
 10  ->     import_pd_df = pd.read_excel(**options)
 11         print(import_pd_df)
[EOF]
(Pdb) options["converters"]["col1"]
<class 'numpy.float64'>
(Pdb) options["converters"]["col2"]
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

as desired.

**Note: You might want to consider just storing your "options" file as a `pickle` file instead of JSON.** That way you can just serialize Python functions and objects (like `np.float64`) to your "options" file. You won't have to do goofy string conversions. I can provide an example if desired, but there are plenty elsewhere.

**Note2: This is not particularly secure.** Be sure that you trust the party that is giving you that `json.json` file. You're open to some pretty serious injection attacks with the code above. `pickle` has similar issues: you'll have to trust the party that's giving you the file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use a string value to represent a Python symbol.

Unfortunately, JSON can only represent number and strings, and knows nothing about symbolic values such as `np.float64` so cannot parse them. Similarly, it would not work to call `pd.read_excel` with string values for those options (but it did work without the quotes, because you were then using the right values - functions, which Python can call).

You would therefore have to do some conversion after reading the JSON input before you obtained a dictionary you could pass to `excel_read`,

Answer (score -1):

When reading JSON formatted data from an external file use `json.load(file_path)` like this:

`import json
with open(file_path, 'r') as j:
    obj = json.load(j)`

Comment: This simply describes a different but equivalent way to read the JSON, but does not address the problem, which is the inability of the JSON parser to understand symbolic values.

Answer (score -1):

try this, read the .json not like string
**json.load(opened)** . load is for a file, loads for a string...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
with open('json.json') as opened:

        options = json.load(opened)

        import_pd_df = pd.read_excel(**options)

        print(import_pd_df)
```

Comment: This simply describes a different but equivalent way to read the JSON, but does not address the problem, which is the inability of the JSON parser to understand symbolic values.